# What's the difference between socketIOClient and webSocket in socket.io in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I have built a `socket` between `React` and `nodejs`. I am using `socketIOClient` all the time on my `react` but I just found that there is another component called `webSocket` from `socket.io-client`. I cannot find much information from official guide. What's the difference between them? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

socket.io have difference transport  methods. websocket is one of them.